# Eclipse setInitialSize doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to set my Eclipse RCP Application's initial size in the suggested way but it doesnt affect the actual size of the window. It doesn't matter what I set the size to the window always appears as fixed with 1020*765 dimensions.

See attached picture (I blanked out some sensitive info). I set the point to 600*400 yet the window appears with the same dimensions. So far no values entered affected the actual size.

I clear the workspace each time and even use -clearPersistedState

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Eclipse 4.3 or 4.2 this is Eclipse bug [418615](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=418615) the fix is scheduled for 4.3.2

Answer (score 0):

By Greg's suggestion I looked for a different way and I could manage by using this code. Seems that under 4.3.1 the configurer's initialSize property never gets used but set to 1024*768 by default. This sets the Application window to the display's size:

```
@Override
 public void postWindowOpen() {
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().setBounds(getDisplaySize());
 }

private Rectangle getDisplaySize() {
    try {
        Display display = Display.getCurrent();
        Monitor monitor = display.getPrimaryMonitor();
        Rectangle rect = monitor.getBounds();
        return rect;
    }
    catch ( Throwable ignore ) {
        return new Rectangle(0,0,1024,768);
    }
}
```

Also for a maximized state you can use:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().setMaximized(true);
```